# Calculating the value based on dynamically replacing placeholders in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains a column `serviceMaxFormula` with a value like `(L*W*H)/6000`

When I run my query I'd like to replace `L`, `W` and `H` with variables that I know.

So far I have ...

```
select 
  serviceID, 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(serviceMaxFormula,'H',30),'W',20),'L',10) as serviceMaxFormula
from carrier_services
```

This gives me value of `serviceMaxFormula` of `(10*20*30)/6000`

How do I now get the value of this calculation? i.e. in this case I would be looking for the number `1`

I have created a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b7b3d/3

Comment: Thank you. I have created a fiddle. I can easily get (10*20*30)/6000 in the query response but not how to actually evaluate this and get the answer of 1

Comment: I dunno. Maybe there's some trick with PREPARE, but this problem smacks of poor schema design to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found only 1 option - is to use variables,

for that you have to replace you formula from `(L*W*H)/6000` to `(@L*@W*@H)/6000`, so now you can do something like this:

```
SET @L = 10;
SET @W = 20;
SET @H = 30;

SELECT (@L*@W*@H)/6000;
```

Result must be:

```
+-----------------+
| (@L*@W*@H)/6000 |
+-----------------+
|          1.0000 |
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN servicemaxformula LIKE '%L%' THEN 10 ELSE 1 END)  
     * MAX(CASE WHEN servicemaxformula LIKE '%W%' THEN 20 ELSE 1 END)  
     * MAX(CASE WHEN servicemaxformula LIKE '%H%' THEN 30 ELSE 1 END)  
     / SUBSTRING_INDEX(servicemaxformula,'/',-1)+0 x
  FROM carrier_services;
```